# Query surge Connection To Azure Databricks failed with error No suitable Driver Found

Tags: jdbc, azure-databricks

i have tried building connection to Query surge from azure data bricks. unfortunately received error message stating " java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:databricks " for driver class "com.simba.spark.jdbc.Driver" , when updated the driver class to "com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver" error message changed to "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver".
help needed if anyone faced same error message what could be the solution to it.
connection i tried to build for querysurge was on URL not on Application.

build connection on both the driver class mentioned and followed manual for building connection but failed to get stable connection as expecting.

Comment: Are you trying to read or write data from SQL database?

Comment: i am trying to load data from azure storage explorer to query surge with intermediate link as data bricks
"https://querysurge.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024979372-Connecting-QuerySurge-to-Azure-Databricks" this is the procedure for creating connection but i am facing errors as i mentioned in my description.